# How to set the sum value on another Textbox using ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to *set* the sum of two Textboxes to another Textbox using ASP.NET MVC, I know this looks easy but I'm not familiarized with MVC. I just have done this just by using a `@ViewBag.mensaje`. This is my code: 
**Model**:

```
public class suma
{
    public int n1 { get; set; }
    public int n2 { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
  // GET: suma

  public ActionResult Index()
  { 
      return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(Models.suma model) 
  {
        int x = model.n1;
        int y = model.n2;
        int total = model.total;
        total = x + y;
        ViewBag.mensaje = (total).ToString();
        return View();
  }
```

**View:**

```
@model bonito2.Models.suma

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "suma", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.n1)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.n2)<br />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <br />

    @ViewBag.mensaje
}
```

My code works **OK** but I'm trying this to work or set the value on a Textbox not in a `@ViewBag.mensaje`. Thanks.

Comment: For example add `Total` property to your model, and on `get` method write `return n1 + n2` (or calculate inside ActionMethod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do as follows:

```
public class suma
{
    public int n1 { get; set; }
    public int n2 { get; set; }
    public int total => n1 + n2;
}
```

Then in the html:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.total)
```

Comment: I tried this but It didn't work, `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.total)` created a new textbox but sum didnt work. It just appear to be blank after clicking button. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

js code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        //this calculates values automatically 
        sum();
        $("#n1, #n2").on("keydown keyup", function() {
            sum();
        });
    });
function sum() {
            var num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
            var num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
            var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('total').value = result;
            }
        }
```

and add this to html

```
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly />
```